# Not getting value in xslt transformer mule esb

Tags: xslt, mule, mule-studio

I facing issue while using xslt transformer..
As input i got response in xml from microsoft connector..And i convert into another form of xml using xslt transformer.
But problem is i didn't get values from particular node..

Below is my flow..Whats wrong with this flow

```
 <flow name="flow1">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <component class="org.com.test" doc:name="Java"/>
        <dynamicsax:invoke-document-service-operation config-ref="Microsoft" serviceAndSoapActionUri="XXXXX" doc:name="Microsoft"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer mimeType="application/xml" doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
        <mulexml:xslt-transformer mimeType="application/xml" xsl-file="src/main/resources/demo.xslt" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT"/>
        <logger message="--&gt; #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="PurchaseOrder" outputPattern="test.xml" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>

    </flow>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<type>
   <id />
   <name />
</type>
```

I didn't get value ..

If i use File as source then i got successful output.. If i used below flow then it run

```
<flow name="flow2">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="Input" moveToDirectory="Backup" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <mulexml:xslt-transformer xsl-file="src/main/resources/demo.xslt" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="Output" outputPattern="test.xml" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<type>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>test</name>
</type>
```

What's wrong with 1st flow..please help to solve this..I need 1st flow to be executed..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dom-to-xml transformer return expected data as xslt required.